# (Google Sheets) How do you get cells to alter based on a certain date?

Tags: date, google-sheets, finance

I'm looking to create a spreadsheet to get a grasp of what my personal finances are saying. Part of this obviously involves putting in income from my job. While I know my shifts in advance so I know how much I will be earning on any given day, I won't actually get the money until the end of the month.

I've created a cell called 'bank balance' based on my current savings, but obviously I don't want to have to physically update this every time I get paid so I'd like to just be able to give Sheets a date where it can update that cell itself based on my payday.

**For example:**
I start off with £100 in my bank account on January 15th. I know I'm going to get paid £400 on January 28th (last working day of the month). I don't want to input that on Jan 15th as that wouldn't be an accurate reflection of my finances. So I input something that tells sheets to add that £400 on to the bank balance cell on Jan 28th for me.

[The example sheet on January 15th][image: 1]

[The example sheet on payday January 28th after automatically adding on the £400 to the bank balance][image: 2]

I've currently got a separate cell for 'work income' that I want to apply this function to (I.E. so that I can tell the sheet to add the total 'work income' to 'bank balance' on payday) but I'm not sure where to go from here.

I've got similar issues with subscriptions leaving my account on various days of the month but the income is my higher priority.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: Your question can be greatly improved if you add a table to the question. [Tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) are a better alternative than spreadsheets to show your data structure.  If you share spreadsheets, make sure to also add images of your sheet to avoid closure of your question, as questions here must be [self](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455/) [contained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149892). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), when you share Google files.

Comment: Create a table with date, income expected. Then use `SUM(income expected column)`